# Unassigned Reference Exception

Tags: unity-game-engine

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable segmentPrefab of Snake has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the segmentPrefab variable of the Snake script in the inspector.

Im making a very simple snake game where you eat the fruit and the snake multiplies and so on, when the snake eats the fruit it creates a segmentprefab clone creates but then i get this error and have no idea how to fix it? please help

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in the error message? Basically this is a wrapper exception for an exposed reference field in the Inspector that is unassigned ...

Comment: That error is fixed now but another problem has happend, when i eat the food a block creates but when i change direction it dissapears. im following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8gUnpeaMbQ

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a prefab to the segmentPrefab variable before you can clone something.
Just select the GameObject on which the Snake script is attached, then in the inspector locate the Snake component and look at the "Segment Prefab" property, it should be empty. Just drag and drop a valid prefab on the field, it should be enough.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingComponents.html

Comment: it isnt empty it says snakeSegment (Transform)

Comment: Okay a bit more context i was following a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8gUnpeaMbQ and the part at 37:19 isnt working for me

Comment: Have you removed the Snake component from the GameObject before creating the SnakeSegment prefab? He does this at 31:42. If you didn't this then you have a Snake component on your prefab with the Segment Prefab property unset. The Snake component must be placed only on the main segment, not the ones added further. Check your prefab and eventually remove its Snake component.

Comment: Im sorry im new by GameObject do you mean the scene on the hierarchy if so then yes i removed it and moved to the assets then added it to the snake GameObject. This is the code that controlls how it grows. private void Grow ()
    {
        Transform segment = Instantiate(this.segmentPrefab);
        segment.position = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].position;

        _segments.Add(segment);
    }

     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Food") {
           Grow();     
        }
       
    }

Comment: The segmentprefab clones come on the hierarchy when i eat the food but when i change direction they disappear

Comment: Yes, gameobjects are the items in the hierarchy. So, if segments are created successfully when you eat food, when the error happens?

Comment: is there a way i can show you what happens cant really explain

Comment: do you have discord or something

Comment: or can we use the unity collab option

Comment: As a general rule on stackoverflow you should make the code available to everybody to get help. However feel free to share your project with me using unity collab, my nickname is Daniels118

Comment: I need your email to add you